# How to read file line by line in Bash script?

Tags: linux, bash, file, io

I have a problem with reading a file line by line with bash script. Here is the script:

```
#!/bin/bash

file="cam.txt"

while IFS=: read -r xf1 xf2 xf3
do
     printf 'Loop: %s %s %s\n' "$xf1" "$xf2" "$xf3"
     f1=$xf1
     f2=$xf2
     f3=$xf3
done < $file
printf 'After: %s %s %s\n' "$f1" "$f2" "$f3"
```

Here is `cam.txt`:

```
192.168.0.159
554
554
```

Here is the output:

```
Loop: 192.168.0.159  
Loop: 554  
Loop: 554  
After: 554
```

What could be the problem?

Comment: Show a sample of your file.

Comment: I added. Thanks for your attention @Mat

Comment: Now it is unclear what you're trying to do. Output is as expected given your code & the input file. Please explain in more detail what you're trying to achieve.

Comment: Try this: `{ read -r xf1; read -r xf2; read -r xf3; } <cam.txt`

Comment: Thank you @Cyrus. it worked

Comment: @Cyrus, impressive mind reading

Comment: Why are you splitting on `:`, when there are no colons in the input file?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your code leads me to believe you want each line in one variable.

Try this script (I know this can be done easier and prettier, but this is a simple and readable example):

```
#!/bin/bash
file="cam.txt"

while read -r line
do
    printf 'Line: %s\n' "$line"

    current=$line
    last=$current
    secondlast=$last

    printf 'Loop: %s %s %s\n' "$current" "$last" "$secondlast"
done < $file

printf 'After: %s %s %s\n' "$current" "$last" "$secondlast"
```

Simpler version:

```
{ read -r first; read -r second; read -r third; } <cam.txt
printf 'After: %s %s %s\n' "$first" "$second" "$third"
```